# How to set target activity with variable

Tags: java, android, variables, android-intent

how can I use variable in intent as target activity?

```
String var1 = et.getText().toString();
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);//MainActivity2.class => var1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how:

```
try {
    // Considering var1 = MainActivity2
    Class cls = Class.forName("package.name." + var1);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, cls);
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I want use variable that user set it not vairable with static value

Comment: @AP4MH I hoped you could figure that out by yourself. Updated my answer. If var1 is not in the format I wrote you can parse the string (I hope).

Comment: when I use your sample I see error under Class.forName that say "Unhandled exeption: java.langClassNotFoundExeption"

Comment: @AP4MH you need to catch an exception that might occur if the class doesn't exist. Updated again.

Comment: Application run fine but when I fill the textbox and click button nothing happend

Comment: @AP4MH debug it? Or do you expect me to write the whole app for you? :)